# Vue binding to external objects

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3

I'm trying to use Vue as a very thin layer to bind existing model objects to a view.

Below is a toy app illustrating my problem. I have a [GainNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GainNode) object, from the Web Audio API. I want to bind its `value` to a slider.

This is trivial in Angular. Two-way binding works with any object, whether part of an Angular component or not. Is there a way to do something similar in Vue?

In the real app, I have big lists of programmatically generated objects. I need to bind them to a component, e.g. `<Knob v-for='channel in channels' v-model='channel.gainNode.gain.value'>`.

UPDATE: I was using Workaround #2 (below), and it appeared to be working great, until I tried `v-model`-binding two components to the same audio parameter. Then it just didn't work in, in totally mysterious ways that I couldn't debug. I eventually gave up and am using getters/setters, which is more boilerplate but has the advantage of, ya know.. actually working.

```js
class MyApp {
        constructor() {
            // core model which I'd prefer to bind to
            this.audio = new AudioContext();
            this.audioNode = this.audio.createGain();
            this.audioNode.gain.value = .8; // want to bind a control to this

            // attempts to add reactivity
            this.reactiveWrapper = Vue.reactive(this.audioNode.gain);
            this.refWrapper = Vue.ref(this.audioNode.gain.value);
        }

        get gainValue() { return this.audioNode.gain.value; }
        set gainValue(value) { this.audioNode.gain.value = value; }
    }
    let appModel = new MyApp();

    let app = Vue.createApp({
        template: '#AppView',
        data() { return {
            // core model which I'd prefer to bind to
            model: appModel,

            // attempt to add reactivity
            dataAliasAudioNode: appModel.audioNode }
        }
    });
    app.mount('#mount');
```

```html
<script type='text/x-template' id='AppView'>
    <div>
        model.audioNode.gain.value: {{model.audioNode.gain.value}}
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div>
        <div>Binding to getter/setter for <code>model.audioNode.gain.value</code> (works)</div>
        <input type='range' min='0' max='1' step='.1' v-model='model.gainValue'>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>Binding directly to <code>model.audioNode.gain.value</code> (doesn't work)</div>
        <input type='range' min='0' max='1' step='.1' v-model='model.audioNode.gain.value'>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>Binding through <code>model.reactiveWrapper</code> (doesn't work)</div>
        <input type='range' min='0' max='1' step='.1' v-model='model.reactiveWrapper.value'>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>Binding through <code>model.refWrapper</code> (doesn't work)</div>
        <input type='range' min='0' max='1' step='.1' v-model='model.refWrapper.value'>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>Binding through <code>dataAliasAudioNode.gain.value</code> (doesn't work)</div>
        <input type='range' min='0' max='1' step='.1' v-model='dataAliasAudioNode.gain.value'>
    </div>
</script>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>

<div id='mount'></div>
```

---

**Question Addendum #1:** In exploring ways to do this, I've discovered (as already noted) that if I bind to a nested portion of a foreign object (`GainNode` the Web Audio API) it's not reactive, but if I build a similar foreign object myself, binding to a nested parameter *is* reactive. Here's example code:

```js
// my version Web Audio API's AudioContext, GainNode, and AudioParam
class AudioParamX {
    constructor() {
        this._value = 0;
    }
    get value() { return this._value; }
    set value(v) { this._value = v; }
}
class ValueParamX extends AudioParamX {
}
class GainNodeX {
    constructor() {
        this.gain = new ValueParamX();
    }
}
class AudioContextX {
    createGain() {
        return new GainNodeX();
    }
}
//==================================================================

class MyApp {
    constructor() {
        this.audio = new AudioContext();
        this.audioNode = this.audio.createGain();

        this.xaudio = new AudioContextX();
        this.xaudioNode = this.xaudio.createGain();
    }
}
let appModel = new MyApp();

let app = Vue.createApp({
    template: '#AppView',
    data() { return { model: appModel } }
});
app.mount('#mount');
```

```html
<script type='text/x-template' id='AppView'>
    <div>
        model.xaudioNode.gain.value: {{model.xaudioNode.gain.value}}
    </div>
    <div>
        model.audioNode.gain.value: {{model.audioNode.gain.value}}
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div>
        <div>Binding to <code>model.xaudioNode.gain.value</code> works.</div>
        <input type='range' min='0' max='1' step='.05' v-model='model.xaudioNode.gain.value'>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>Binding to <code>model.audioNode.gain.value</code> doesn't. Why?</div>
        <input type='range' min='0' max='1' step='.05' v-model='model.audioNode.gain.value'>
    </div>
</script>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>

<div id='mount'></div>
```

---

**Workaround #1:**

So after more exploration, I've come up with one workaround which reduces the boilerplate of a getter/setter. I either:

1. Create my own version of `ref` (no clue `Vue.ref` doesn't work) or
2. `Proxy` the object and call `$forceUpdate` when the setter is called.

Both of these work, with the disadvantage that I then must expose the proxy as a member and bind to *it* rather than the original object. But it's better than exposing both a getter and setter and it works with `v-model`.

```js
class MyApp {
        createWrapper(obj, field) {
          return {
              get [field]() { return obj[field]; },
              set [field](v) { obj[field] = v; }
          }
        }
        createProxy(obj) {
            let update = () => this.forceUpdate();
            return new Proxy(obj, {
                  get(target, prop) { return target[prop] },
                  set(target, prop, value) {
                      update();
                      return target[prop] = value
                  }
            });
        }

        watch(obj, prop) {
            hookSetter(obj, prop, () => this.forceUpdate());
        }
        constructor() {
            this.audio = new AudioContext();

            // core model which I'd prefer to bind to
            this.audioNode = this.audio.createGain();
            this.audioNode.gain.value = .1; // want to bind a control to this
            this.audioNode.connect(this.audio.destination);

            // attempts to add reactivity
            this.wrapper = this.createWrapper(this.audioNode.gain, 'value');
            this.proxy = this.createProxy(this.audioNode.gain);
        }
    }
    let appModel = new MyApp();

    let app = Vue.createApp({
        template: '<AppView :model="model" />',
        data() { return { model: appModel } },
    });
    app.component('AppView', {
        template: '#AppView',
        props: ['model'],
        mounted() {
            this.model.forceUpdate = () => this.$forceUpdate();
        }
    })
    app.mount('#mount');
```

```html
<style>body { user-select: none; }</style>

<script type='text/x-template' id='AppView'>
    <div>
        <div>model.audioNode.gain.value: {{model.audioNode.gain.value}}</div>
        <div>model.wrapper.value: {{model.wrapper.value}}</div>
        <div>model.proxy.value: {{model.wrapper.value}}</div>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div>
        <div>Binding directly to <code>model.audioNode.gain.value</code> (doesn't work)</div>
        <input type='range' min='0' max='1' step='.05' v-model='model.audioNode.gain.value'>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>Binding through <code>model.wrapper.value</code> (works)</div>
        <input type='range' min='0' max='1' step='.05' v-model='model.wrapper.value'>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>Binding through <code>model.proxy.value</code> (works)</div>
        <input type='range' min='0' max='1' step='.05' v-model='model.proxy.value'>
    </div>
</script>

<div id='mount'></div>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
```

---

**Workaround #2:**

Another workaround is to patch the accessor I want to watch and call `$forceUpdate` in it. This has the *least* boilerplate. I just call `watch(obj, prop)` and that property becomes reactive.

This is a fairly acceptable workaround, to my taste. However, I'm not sure how well these workaround schemes will work when I start moving things into child components. I'm going to try that next. I also still don't understand why `Vue.reference` doesn't do the same thing.

I'd like to do this in the most Vue native way possible, and it seems like it would be a pretty typical use case.

```js
    class MyApp {
        watch(obj, prop) {
            hookObjectSetter(obj, prop, () => this.forceUpdate());
        }
        constructor() {
            this.audio = new AudioContext();

            // core model which I'd prefer to bind to
            this.audioNode = this.audio.createGain();
            this.audioNode.gain.value = .1; // want to bind a control to this
            this.watch(this.audioNode.gain, 'value'); // make it reactive
        }
    }
    let appModel = new MyApp();


    let app = Vue.createApp({
        template: '<AppView :model="model" />',
        data() { return { model: appModel } },
    });
    app.component('AppView', {
        template: '#AppView',
        props: ['model'],
        mounted() {
            this.model.forceUpdate = () => this.$forceUpdate();
        }
    })
    app.mount('#mount');


    function hookObjectSetter(obj, prop, callback) {
        let descriptor = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(obj, prop);
        if (!descriptor) {
            obj = Object.getPrototypeOf(obj);
            descriptor = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(obj, prop);
        }
        if (descriptor && descriptor.configurable) {
            let set = descriptor.set || (v => descriptor.value = v);
            let get = descriptor.get || (v => descriptor.value);
            Object.defineProperty(obj, prop, {
                configurable: false, // prevent double-hooking; sorry anybody else!
                get,
                set(v) {
                    callback();
                    return set.apply(this, arguments);
                },
            });
        }
    }
```

```html
<script type='text/x-template' id='AppView'>
    <div>
        <div>model.audioNode.gain.value: {{model.audioNode.gain.value}}</div>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div>
        <div>Binding directly to <code>model.audioNode.gain.value</code> with custom `watch` (works)</div>
        <input type='range' min='0' max='1' step='.05' v-model='model.audioNode.gain.value'>
    </div>
</script>

<div id='mount'></div>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your question is exciting so I decided to spend hours figuring out the answer.

#### TLDR

- Built-in objects (objects that are created by browser API) can't be converted into the reactive form so mutating its properties will not trigger re-render
- Vue is not fully selective re-render so when it does re-render the template, some blocks that are even not reactive will be updated too.

#### Let's wrap up the problem:

- The reactive does NOT work when mutating a property of a Web Audio API object (actually any built-in object will be the same)
- The reactive does work when mutating that same property in a setter

#### Explanation

First, we need to know **What happens when Vue renders a value on the template?** Let's consider this template:

```
{{ model.audioNode.gain.value }}
```

If `model` is a reactive object (which is created by `reactive`, `ref`, or `computed` ...), Vue will create a getter that converts each object on the chain into reactive. So, these following objects will be converted into the reactive form using the `Vue.reactive` function: `model.audioNode`, `model.audioNode.gain`

But just some types that can be converted to a reactive object. Here is [the code from Vue reactive package](https://github.com/vuejs/core/blob/main/packages/reactivity/src/reactive.ts#L43)

```js
function targetTypeMap(rawType: string) {
  switch (rawType) {
    case 'Object':
    case 'Array':
      return TargetType.COMMON
    case 'Map':
    case 'Set':
    case 'WeakMap':
    case 'WeakSet':
      return TargetType.COLLECTION
    default:
      return TargetType.INVALID
  }
}
```

As we can see, types that other than `Object`, `Array`, `Map`, `Set`, `WeakMap`, and `WeakSet` will be invalid. To know what type of your object, you can call `yourObject.toString()` ([what Vue is actually using](https://github.com/vuejs/core/blob/main/packages/shared/src/index.ts#L67)). Any custom class that does not modify the `toString` method will be `Object` type and can be made reactive. In your example code `model` is `object` type, `model.audioNode` is type `GainNode`. So it can NOT be converted to a reactive object and mutating its property will not trigger Vue re-render.

So **Why the setter method works**?

It actually does NOT work. Let's consider this snippet:

```js
class MyApp {
        constructor() {
            this.audio = new AudioContext();
            this.audioNode = this.audio.createGain();
            this.audioNode.gain.value = .8;
        }

        get gainValue() { return this.audioNode.gain.value; }
        set gainValue(value) { this.audioNode.gain.value = value; }
    }
    let appModel = new MyApp();

    let app = Vue.createApp({
        template: '#AppView',
        data() { 
          return {
                model: appModel,
              }
        }
    });
    app.mount('#mount');
```

```html
<script type='text/x-template' id='AppView'>
    <div>
        model.audioNode.gain.value: {{model.audioNode.gain.value}}
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div>
        <div>Binding to getter/setter for <code>model.gainValue</code> (does NOT work)</div>
        <input type='range' min='0' max='1' step='.1' :value="model.audioNode.gain.value" @input="model.gainValue=$event.target.value">
    </div>
</script>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>

<div id='mount'></div>
```

The setter in the snippet above does NOT work. Let's consider another snippet:

```js
class MyApp {
        constructor() {
            this.audio = new AudioContext();
            this.audioNode = this.audio.createGain();
            this.audioNode.gain.value = .8;
        }

        get gainValue() { return this.audioNode.gain.value; }
        set gainValue(value) { this.audioNode.gain.value = value; }
    }
    let appModel = new MyApp();

    let app = Vue.createApp({
        template: '#AppView',
        data() { 
          return {
                model: appModel,
              }
        }
    });
    app.mount('#mount');
```

```html
<script type='text/x-template' id='AppView'>
    <div>
        model.audioNode.gain.value: {{model.audioNode.gain.value}}
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div>
        <div>Binding to getter/setter for <code>model.gainValue</code> (does work)</div>
        <input type='range' min='0' max='1' step='.1' :value="model.gainValue" @input="model.gainValue=$event.target.value">
    </div>
</script>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>

<div id='mount'></div>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>

<div id='mount'></div>
```

The setter in the snippet above does work. Take a look at that line `<input type='range' min='0' max='1' step='.1' :value="model.gainValue" @input="model.gainValue=$event.target.value">` It is actually what happened when you using `v-model="model.gainValue"`. The reason it works is the line `:value="model.gainValue"` will trigger Vue re-render anytime `model.gainValue` is updated. And **Vue is not fully selective re-render.** So when the whole template is re-render the block `{{ model.audioNode.gain.value }}` will be re-rendered too.

To prove that Vue is not fully selective re-render, let's consider this snippet:

```js
class MyApp {
            constructor() {
                this.audio = new AudioContext();
                this.audioNode = this.audio.createGain();
                this.audioNode.gain.value = .8;
            }

            get gainValue() { return this.audioNode.gain.value; }
            set gainValue(value) { this.audioNode.gain.value = value; }
        }
        let appModel = new MyApp();

        let app = Vue.createApp({
            template: '#AppView',
            data() {
                return {
                    model: appModel,
                    anIndependentProperty: 1
                }
            },
            methods: {
              update(event){
                this.model.audioNode.gain.value = event.target.value
                this.anIndependentProperty = event.target.value
              }
            }
        });
        app.mount('#mount');
```

```html
<script type='text/x-template' id='AppView'>
        <div>
            model.audioNode.gain.value: {{model.audioNode.gain.value}}
        </div>
        <div>
            anIndependentProperty: {{anIndependentProperty}}
        </div>
        <hr>
        <div>
            <div>anIndependentProperty trigger re-render so the template will be updated</div>
            <input type='range' min='0' max='1' step='.1' :value="model.audioNode.gain.value" @input="update">
        </div>
    </script>

    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>

    <div id='mount'></div>
```

In the example above the `anIndependentProperty` is reactive and it will trigger Vue re-render anytime it is updated. When Vue re-render the template the block `{{model.audioNode.gain.value}}` will be update too.

#### Solution

This solution only works for the case using properties in the template. If you want to use the `computed` from your class properties, you have to roll with setter/getter method.

```js
class MyApp {
  constructor() {
    this.audio = new AudioContext();
    this.audioNode = this.audio.createGain();
    this.audioNode.gain.value = .8;
  }
}
let appModel = new MyApp();

let app = Vue.createApp({
  template: '#AppView',
  data() {
    return {
      model: appModel,
      reactiveControl: 0
    }
  },
});
app.mount('#mount');
```

```html
<script type='text/x-template' id='AppView'>
  <input type="hidden" :value="reactiveControl">
  <div>
    <div>Binding to <code>model.audioNode.gain.value (works):</code> {{model.audioNode.gain.value}} </div>
    <input type='range' min='0' max='1' step='.1' :value="model.audioNode.gain.value" @input="model.audioNode.gain.value=$event.target.value; reactiveControl++">
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>Binding to other property <code>model.audioNode.channelCount (works):</code> {{model.audioNode.channelCount}}</div>
    <input type='range' min='1' max='32' step='1' :value="model.audioNode.channelCount" @input="model.audioNode.channelCount=$event.target.value; reactiveControl++">
  </div>
  You can bind to any property now...
</script>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>

<div id='mount'></div>
```

Please notice this line:

```
<input type="hidden" :value="reactiveControl">
```

Whenever the `reactiveControl` variable changes, the template will be updated and other variables will be updated too. So you just need to change the value of `reactiveControl` whenever you update your class properties.

Comment: First: I appreciate the effort you've gone to! I'm obsessed with this problem at the moment myself. Second: when you say "actually any built-in object", what does "built-in" mean? Native? Built by the browser? I just updated the question with a second example, where the Web API object is not tracked, by a similar object that I built myself is. Re-reading your answer, I guess the answer is "anything not in Vue's `targetTypeMap`". Is that correct?

Comment: I see how your code is getting an update to trigger, but that requires a custom update function in the view.  Right now it's small, but if I want to bind to a lot of different objects and just want to use `v-model` to bind to the target property, I'd not going to work. I updated my post with a few workarounds I've found. Workaround 2 seems like less boilerplate than what you've written (leaving side the `hookSetter` function which can be reused by every class).  Do you see any problems with it?

Comment: @Mud Let's take a look at [how Vue defines a type of an object](https://github.com/vuejs/core/blob/main/packages/shared/src/index.ts#L67). It calls `yourObject.toString().slice(8, -1)`. Built-in objects in my term are objects that are created from browser API. You guessed correctly, anything not in Vue's `targetTypeMap` will be invalid. Note: your custom class is `object` type and can be made reactive

Comment: @Mud I prefer the getter/setter method in your original question. It seems like a more natural way cause they are just your class properties and you don't have to do anything with Vue.

Comment: The thing is... I have class properties that I simply want to bind to. I'm being required to create *two additional properties, per property*, for no other reason than Vue. Instead of 20 members on my class, I have 60 because I can't tell Vue how to watch a thing. In Angular that would be 20 members. My `watch` method drops that back down to 20. So right now it's the most appealing option to me. I just wish I could find a more native way to tell Vue to watch these properties.

Comment: @Mud The downside of the `$forceUpdate` method is that it can NOT update the computed properties which depend on your class properties. So if you wish to use `computed` with your class so you have to use the `setter/getter` method

Comment: The `setter/getter` is the preferred way on OOP because you can hide your class's properties and your logic and just expose what is needed for the consumer. You can control how property is updated too. But it is javascript so, anyway, anything can work. I just updated my answer to add a workaround that I think is the best fit for your case