# Vue binding to external object with SFC

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3

I asked [a very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73285075/501459) a few weeks ago, trying to bind a UI control to a web audio [AudioParam](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioParam) object in a reactive manner. The only thing I could make work reliably was using a getter/setter on my model object. That wasn't too bad when not using the composition API. Here's *that* in action:

```js
class MyApp {
        constructor() {
            // core model which I'd prefer to bind to
            this.audio = new AudioContext();
            this.audioNode = this.audio.createGain();
            this.audioNode.gain.value = .8; // want to bind a control to this

            // attempts to add reactivity
            this.reactiveWrapper = Vue.reactive(this.audioNode.gain);
            this.refWrapper = Vue.ref(this.audioNode.gain.value);
        }

        get gainValue() { return this.audioNode.gain.value; }
        set gainValue(value) { this.audioNode.gain.value = value; }
    }
    let appModel = new MyApp();

    let app = Vue.createApp({
        template: '#AppView',
        data() { return { model: appModel } }
    });
    app.mount('#mount');
```

```html
<script type='text/x-template' id='AppView'>
    <div>
        model.audioNode.gain.value: {{model.audioNode.gain.value}}
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div>
        <div>Binding to getter/setter (works)</div>
        <input type='range' min='0' max='1' step='.1' v-model='model.gainValue'>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>Binding directly to <code>model.audioNode.gain.value</code> (doesn't work)</div>
        <input type='range' min='0' max='1' step='.1' v-model='model.audioNode.gain.value'>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>Binding to <code>reactive(model.audioNode.gain)</code> (doesn't work)</div>
        <input type='range' min='0' max='1' step='.1' v-model='model.reactiveWrapper.value'>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>Binding to <code>ref(model.audioNode.gain.value)</code> (doesn't work)</div>
        <input type='range' min='0' max='1' step='.1' v-model='model.refWrapper.value'>
    </div>
</script>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>

<div id='mount'></div>
```

Now I'm trying to use the composition API in a SFC (single file component). I'm having the same issue, but this time the solution requires even *more* boilerplate. Unfortunately this can't be a runnable snippet, so you'll have to take my word that, exactly as in the example above, trying to use `reactive` on the AudioParam doesn't work:

```html
<script setup>
import { reactive, computed } from "vue";

let audio = new AudioContext();
let volume = audio.createGain(); // I want to bind to this

// this doesn't work
let reactiveGain = reactive(volume.gain);

// this also doesn't work
const gainComputed = computed({
  get: () => volume.gain.value,
  set: val => volume.gain.value = val,
})

// This does.
// Is it possible to achieve this effect without all this boilerplate?
// Also, such that I can still use `v-model` in my template?
class Model {
  set gain(value) { volume.gain.value = value; }
  get gain() { return volume.gain.value; }
}
let model = reactive(new Model());

</script>

<template>
  <div>
    Volume: {{ model.gain.toFixed(2) }}
  </div>

  <div>
    This works
    <input type="range" min="0" max="1" step=".01" v-model="model.gain">
  </div>

  <div>
    This doesn't
    <input type="range" min="0" max="1" step=".01" v-model="reactiveGain.value">
  </div>

  <div>
    This doesn't
    <input type="range" min="0" max="1" step=".01" v-model="gainComputed">
  </div>
</template>
```

Is there a better way to reactively bind to objects outside of Vue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with this kind of binding is that it works in one direction, it's possible to update original `volume.gain.value` on Vue model changes, but it's impossible to update Vue model when `volume.gain` class instance changes `value` internally. Given that `volume.gain` is an instance of `AudioParam`, `value` can change based on defined constraints, e.g. `minValue`. This would require to replace these native classes with extended reactivity-aware classes, this depends on specific classes whether it's possible and how this needs to be done. `volume.gain` is read-only, in the case of `AudioParam` replacing `gain` with fully reactive instance of `MyAudioParam` would require to extend the whole hierarchy of classes, starting from `AudioContext`.

Vue 3 provides limited support for the reactivity of classes. `reactive` transforms own enumerable properties into reactive ones. The rest of members cannot be expected to be affected automatically. `reactive` can have destructive effect on classes that weren't specifically written with it in mind.

Third-party classes may be implemented in arbitrary ways as long as it fits their normal use, while their use with `reactive` cannot be considered one, and their ability to provide reactivity needs to be determined by trial and error.

It's evident that native behaviour of `volume.gain.value` already relies on `get`/`set` to make `AudioParam` react to value changes, so `value` is not own enumerable property but a descriptor on `AudioParam.prototype`. The original implementation didn't work because `volume.gain.value` is not reactive in neither of these cases and its changes cannot cause a view to be updated. `reactive` shouldn't be used on it because it won't help to make `value` reactive but can have negative effects on class instance based on its implementation.

A class isn't needed for `reactive(new Model())`. Vue reactivity was primarily designed to be used with plain objects.

Considering that the binding is one way (model value changes update native value behind it, but not vice versa), it's correct to explicitly define local state and update native value on its changes. If this is a common case, it can be a helper to reduce boilerplate:

```
let createPropModel = (obj, key) => {
  let state = ref(obj[key]);

  watch(state, v => { obj[key] = v }, { immediate: true });

  return state;
};

let gainRef = createPropModel(volume.gain, 'value');
```

Alternatively, this can be done with writable computed, but it should involve local state too, and the implementation is less straightforward:

```
let createPropModel = (obj, key) => {
  let state = ref(obj[key]);

  return computed({
    get: () => state.value,
    set: (v) => { state.value = v; obj[key] = v },
  });
};

let gainRef = createPropModel(volume.gain, 'value');
```

Comment: Both of your `createPropModel` functions are not reactive in the way I'm expecting. [Here's a demo](https://tetzfiles.com/temp/vue-sfc-reactivity). I used my `wrapReference` for the first two sliders. The next four sliders are your `createPropModel` implementations. Note that my sliders respond to changes from every slider on the page, and the binding shows the actual value of the AudioNode. Your sliders don't respond to changes from other sliders. This is an issue, because I may have multiple controls bound to a parameter at the same time (e.g. main fader and channel strip knob).

Comment: You're misusing `createPropModel` in this example. They return a state. If you need a state to be shared in this comp, you need to call `createPropModel(volume.gain, 'value')` once and reuse a ref. If you need it to be global, you need to call it once per app and reuse between comps. It's the same as with other Vue global state cases. As for wrapReference, it abuses Vue reactivity. As the post explains, volume.gain.value doesn't provide anything that could make it reactive in terms of Vue, and get/set accessors are ignored by `reactive`.

Comment: `v-model="gain2.value"` just updates a view and forces volume.gain.value current value to be read, basically serves as  `this.$forceUpdate()`. You can put a breakpoint into `get` in `wrapReactive` and see that the value is retrieved on every update in the app, not just the one that's relevant to `gain` and `gain2`. And `gain.value` and `gain2.value` changes are the ones that force these updates.

Comment: **"If you need a state to be shared in this comp [..] reuse a ref"** Ah, OK, fair enough.  But I liked the fact distant, uncoupled parts of the system could decide to watch part of the audio graph without any knowledge of these special wrapper and they stay in sync. **"wrapReference, it abuses Vue reactivity"** Not really knowing Vue, I don't know how this is any more or less of an abuse than your constructs.  **"the value is retrieved on every update in the app"** Just tested this. I can see how that's worse. Accepting your solution.

Comment: Glad it worked. It would be good if it were possible to watch on gain as is but it's not going to happen for a global thing that is unaware of Vue reactivity. I barely mentioned this approach because it's impractical in this case. Basically you'd need to extend a hierarchy - first AudioContext class, then extend Node class that is returned by `createGain`, then replace its `gain` property with extended AudioParam class that replaces original `value` with Vue computed. Unless you need bidirectional binding with that class, that's a total overkill, also Vue reactivity comes with performance hit

Comment: I can't get this to work in an actual app. In particular "If you need it to be global, you need to call it once per app and reuse between comps".  How do you share it between components? You can't pass it as a prop then bind it to something. Vue doesn't like you to modify prop values.

Comment: This restriction applies only to prop values. You still can mutate an object passed through a prop, but it's considered a bad practice. I talk about global store or an analog, i.e. just `ref` or reactive that is imported from a module where it was called once. Here https://vuejs.org/guide/scaling-up/state-management.html

Comment: So if my mixer channel has a control for an AudioParam, and I need a child to have duplicate a control for the same thing (like this https://i.imgur.com/LKqhDiO.png), then  I have to start creating *global objects* in order to share them? That just seems insane to me. I tried storing these things in my model, but that doesn't work either, because Vue has so much magic going on under the good. The more I use it, the more I hate it. I've already gone back to my old, shitty version which triggers a billion more change detection cycles than I want, because... it at least works.

Comment: If there's only one mixer and there's only one "the same thing" per app then it makes sense to use global store. What is your concern with it? Technically you need to a common state in a component that is a parent to both places where this param is used, and it's propagated to all children (e.g. with provide/inject). If a parent is high enough, e.g. App component then there's no practical difference between this hierarchy-aware state and global state.

Comment: There far more than one of "the same thing" and I don't want global state because it's *bad*; objects should exist in the smallest possible scope. **you need to a common state in a component that is a parent to both places where this param is used, and it's propagated to all children** That's what I'm trying to do. It's the "propagate to all children" that doesn't work. I was passing things via props, but apparently props should not be mutated. So then what? In Angular, separating model from viewmodel is trivial. In Vue, it seems like it wants to *be* the model.

Comment: It's not bad if it serves the purpose and there's no risk of regretting it being global (multiple instances, etc). You can check on global stores, this is an established practice. There are only a couple ways in which you can exchange data across the app, besides props. As I said, provide/inject is one of them. Basically provide(reactive({ foo, setFoo() {...} })) in a common parent. When this is done in root comp, it's global state, otherwise it's less global. It's preferable to explicitly mutate it through setFoo, etc to make it more debuggable, otherwise it's not better than mutating props

Comment: @Mud There's a reason if this serves a good purpose and follows good practices. This isn't Angular and some things are different. Angular rigorously forces hierarchical DI. React and Vue don't. You'd move mixer state to singleton service in Angular, which is basically the same thing as global store. This looks like a proper case for global store in Vue, if you ask me. Any way, it's up to you. You can mutate objects that are passed through props. It's an antipattern but it's allowed.

Comment: **follows good practices** Globals are a legitimately bad practice, and not for cargo cult reasons, especially in this case. **Angular rigorously forces hierarchical DI.** Angular doesn't force me to expose the guts of some arbitrary model class to the global scope because it can't bind to it any other way. **You can mutate objects that are passed through props. It's an antipattern but it's allowed.** The reason I'm bitching about it is that it's not letting me. Well, it does, but then it overwrites them when re-rendering, which is why you're not supposed to do it.

Comment: "Angular doesn't force me" - when a singleton is needed, it's needed. I'm very aware of the problem with globals. Global store is not the same antipattern, primarily because it's supposed to be used in specific cases that fit it well.  There's NgRx in A2 as well. Your case is one of them, it's up to you if you want to solve it properly. If you're relatively new to the way things work in Vue, at least consider exploring how things are done there, including global stores (e.g. Pinia) and the thing with props. You'd have the same problem with props in A2 because Vue borrowed its two-way binding.

Comment: **"when a singleton is needed"** That isn't what I said. You responded to the first half of a sentence, where the second half was relevant. **"You'd have the same problem with props in A2 because Vue borrowed its two-way binding."** This is demonstrably untrue. In A2, I can bind directly to an audioparam and it just works. I tried Vue because it's MVVM as a single import, which I much prefer aesthetically.  It also, at least in my imagination, had the potentially for better performance in my case, because there it doesn't use Zone.js.

Comment: My point about singletons is that you'd use a service to share data between different parts of the app in A2 and wouldn't bothered about it being 'global', it's idiomatic and right solution when it's applicable. The same for stores in Vue/React. Some parts don't differ as much as they seem to. Did you try this binding with AudioParam in A2? I don't see how it would work, you'd likely need to wrap it with an observable, data flow would be roughly the same as with reactive objects in Vue, and you'd run into the same problems by keeping these observables in local state instead of lifting it up.

Comment: The performance isn't that straightforward. Vue uses proxies that are much less hacky than zones, but the last time I checked (3-4 years ago) proxies were ridiculously slower than plain objects, didn't check how it changed in up-to-date browsers. It's possible that with uncareful use of reactivity the performance in Vue may be slower than a similar code with A2 zones+change detection, but these are the bottlenecks that rarely ever determine the  performance of properly designed realworld app

Answer (score 0):

OK, the best I've been able to come up with is this. I'll post it as a potential answer to my question, but wait to see if someone has something better before I accept it.

I created a class for wrapping an [`AudioParam`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioParam):

```js
import { reactive } from "vue";

export function wrapReactive(obj, field) {
    return reactive({
      set value(value) { obj[field] = value; },
      get value() { return obj[field]; }
    });
}
```

```html
<script setup>
import { wrapReactive } from "./wrapReactive.mjs";

let audio = new AudioContext();
let volume = audio.createGain();

let gain = wrapReactive(volume.gain, 'value');
</script>

<template>
  <div>
    Volume: {{ gain.value.toFixed(2) }}
  </div>

  <div>
    <input type="range" min="0" max="1" step=".01" v-model="gain.value">
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: I don't expect it to behave differently than `reactive(volume.gain)` and `gainComputed`. The problem is that there's still no real two-way binding. Can't say on which circumstances it can be the case but if AudioParam hits maxValue and updates its own value, this won't be reflected by Vue model.

Comment: Thankfully I'm not concerned with it updating its own value. I'm constraining the parameters appropriate and have already built a full multichannel mixer with effects chains using this approach (non-SFC) and it's working fine for my purposes. However, it *does* behave differently than `reactive(volume.gain)` and `gainComputed`, neither of which update the view when changed by *my* code. See the non-SFC example.

Comment: I see where a computed falls short. It caches `get` value, and since volume.gain.value is not reactive, it never updates the visible value.By putting an instance of somebody else's class (native in this case) into `reactive` you have a chance to ruin it, this fortunately doesn't happen in this case, but not guaranteed.  I'll post an answer soon. For one-way binding of external value as in your case, ref+watch is preferable.